# Prove that $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Prove that $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ has a convergent subsequence,

where $a_n:= \begin{cases} \min \{2n^2+3n^3+4n^4, \ 7\}, & \text{when $n$ is odd,} \\ \min \{100, \ n^7\}, & \text{when $n$ is even.} \end{cases}$

How would I go about proving this? I'm not too sure how to start.

Comment: See my edit to the question for proper MathJax usage. But I wonder if you can tell me why you treated the word "where" as if it were the start of a new sentence rather than a continuation of a sentence already underway. I've seen people do that here many times and I don't know where they're getting that.

Comment: Sorry still learning how to use MathJax. Not sure why I wrote it like that, probably just a mistake,

Comment: @james15c : Very large numbers of people do that here. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $2n^2+3n^3+4n^4 \ge 7$ for $n\ge 1$ and $n^7 \ge 100$ for $n\ge 2$.
Therefore, 
$$ a_n = 7 \qquad \text{when $n$ is odd}$$
and 
$$ a_n = 100 \qquad \text{when $n$ is even} $$
Hence, you can just take odd or even sub-sequences.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Compute $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6$. Then you should see what happens...

> You get $7,100,7,100,7,100$.